# Getting specific combination of interaction as variable in logistic regression with R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, regression, glm

I have this dataset and want to perform a regression analysis on it. I have to predictive variables urban_rural and religious. Now I want to have two specific interaction variables: 1.) Urban/not religious and 2.) Rural/religious. I know that interaction is possible through the sign *, but this does not give me the desired combination of interaction. I guess one has to set the reference variable manually?

```
structure(list(urban_rural = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Urban", "Rural", "Refugee camp"
), class = "factor"), religious = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Religious", "Somewhat religious", 
"Not religious"), class = "factor"), family_role_recoded = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Agree/strongly agree", 
"Disagree/strongly disagree", "Don't know"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
250L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used these regression models:

```
model1 <- glm(family_role_recoded ~ urban_rural,
              family=binomial(link='logit'),
              subset = (family_role_recoded != "Don't know" & urban_rural != "Refugee camp"), 
              data=dataset)

model2 <- glm(family_role_recoded ~ religious,
              family=binomial(link='logit'),
              subset = (family_role_recoded != "Don't know" & urban_rural != "Refugee camp"), 
              data=dataset)

model3 <- glm(family_role_recoded ~ urban_rural + religious,
              family=binomial(link='logit'),
              subset = (family_role_recoded != "Don't know" & urban_rural != "Refugee camp"), 
              data=dataset)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Subset them outside `glm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the reference for `religious` to be `"Somewhat religious"` first. We can look at the results first :

```
library(broom)
dataset$religious = relevel(dataset$religious,ref="Somewhat religious")

fit0 = glm(family_role_recoded ~ urban_rural*religious,data=dataset,family=binomial())

    # A tibble: 6 x 5
  term                                   estimate std.error statistic    p.value
  <chr>                                     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 (Intercept)                             -0.902      0.181   -4.99      6.03e-7
2 urban_ruralRural                        -0.484      0.532   -0.910     3.63e-1
3 religiousReligious                      -0.0141     0.456   -0.0308    9.75e-1
4 religiousNot religious                   1.47       0.391    3.76      1.67e-4
5 urban_ruralRural:religiousReligious      0.995      1.14     0.876     3.81e-1
6 urban_ruralRural:religiousNot religio…   0.201      0.993    0.203     8.39e-1
```

You have one of the terms `rural/religious`. Intuitively, the `Urban/Not religious` term would be the flip of `urban_ruralRural:religiousNot religio`. We can also manually define the interaction terms we need:

```
dataset$Rural_religious = with(dataset,as.numeric(urban_rural=="Rural" & religious=="Religious"))

dataset$Urban_not_religious = with(dataset,as.numeric(urban_rural=="Urban" & religious=="Not religious"))

fit = glm(family_role_recoded ~ 0+urban_rural+religious+Urban_not_religious+Rural_religious,data=dataset,family=binomial())

tidy(fit)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  term                   estimate std.error statistic     p.value
  <chr>                     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 urban_ruralUrban        -0.902      0.181   -4.99   0.000000603
2 urban_ruralRural        -1.39       0.500   -2.77   0.00556    
3 religiousReligious      -0.0141     0.456   -0.0308 0.975      
4 religiousNot religious   1.67       0.913    1.83   0.0667     
5 Urban_not_religious     -0.201      0.993   -0.203  0.839      
6 Rural_religious          0.995      1.14     0.876  0.381
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a post hoc test. For that you can use the R package "emmeans"